# Configure IntelliJ auto-completion for gradle script in kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I am trying out **gradle-script-kotlin** with simple hello-world application in IntelliJ. But **IntelliJ** auto-completion doesn't popup in **build.gradle.kts** file.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples/hello-world

**build.gradle.kts:**

```
apply<ApplicationPlugin>()

configure<ApplicationPluginConvention> {
    mainClassName = ".HelloWorld"
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    setSourceCompatibility(1.8)
    setTargetCompatibility(1.8)
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
}
```

**settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'
```

I have IntelliJ kotlin plugin and gradle plugin installed and using gradle 3.0. The sample application works with gradle commands.

**How to configure IntelliJ to enable auto-completion on build.gradle.kts file?**

I'm using IntelliJ 2016.2.2 with kotlin plugin version: 1.0.3-release-IJ2016.1-120

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem. Gradle script Kotlin requires version 1.1x of the IntelliJ Kotlin plugin.

Follow these steps to install it:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples#install-idea-kotlin-plugin

The regular update channel only updates to version 1.0.3x right now.

*Update 18/06:*
The github readme has been updated to include:
`(Note: this version will not work with the official Gradle 3.0 release, stick to the official EAP 1.1 from JetBrains if you intend to use Gradle 3.0)`

If you manually installed version 1.1.0-dev-2222 earlier, uninstall it and restart IntelliJ.

#### Install version 1.1.x from the EAP Channel

This version works with Kotlin-Script in Gradle 3.0.

In IntelliJ, press:
`Tools => Kotlin => Configure Kotlin Updates.`
Select
`Early Access Preview 1.1`
and press
`Check for updates now`.

Download the latest plugin.
*If it gives an error, just restart IntelliJ, it will have installed the plugin.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried that but I got `ClassCastException: org.gradle.script.lang.kotlin.support.GradleKotlinScriptDependenciesResolver cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.ScriptDependenciesResolver` exceptions in the event log. May be it has to do something with IntelliJ version as well. I'm using IntelliJ 2016.2.1

Answer (score 3):

I tried gradle 3.1 with kotlin-plugin-1.1.0-dev-2222.zip in intellij 2.5. And it works for me.

Here is my intellij version:
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

And the steps:

1, Download the kotlin-plugin-1.1.0-dev-2222.zip in https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples and install the plugin in Idea
2, Create a gradle java project in Idea, and choose to use gradle wrapper
3, In the terminal, under the project directory, use "./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=3.1" to switch to gradle 3.1
4, Create a file "build.gradle.kts" under the root directory of the project
5, Add `rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'` in the settings.gradle file
6, Add codes in build.gradle.kts, and if the auto-completion does not work, try "Refresh all projects" in the Gradle Tool Window.
7, If it still not work, restart your Idea

Here is a github repo: https://github.com/kolyjjj/gradle-kotlin-test

Answer (score -2):

Try re-importing the project by selecting `settings.gradle`.