# IntelliJ autocompletion for included gradle script kotlin files

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to use [`gradle-script-kotlin`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/) to automate a complicated build process, using IntelliJ as an editor. Following the advice found in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966625/configure-intellij-auto-completion-for-gradle-script-in-kotlin), a colleague has gotten proper syntax highlighting in the `build.gradle.kts` file, however, because of its complexity, I'm trying to split it up into a number of smaller files using the [apply from](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/947cc32c288633223909269b0c111667599cfb66/samples/modularity/build.gradle.kts) example:

```
apply { 
    for (script in otherKotlinScripts)
        from("buildscripts/$script.kts") 
}
```

Alas, the completion only seems to actually work on `build.gradle.kts`. On other kotlin-script files, free functions and anything that I `import` work just fine, but gradle-specific things such as this `task` closure:

```
task("foo") {
    // intelliJ can't seem to figure out what the receiver is here,
    // task itself gets highlighted in red, and its members fail
    // to complete.
}
```

Is there a way to allow intellij to detect included files as gradle scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I wasn't using the correct filenames. The current version of the kotlin intellij plugin at time of writing seems to complete correctly any file that ends with `.gradle.kts`. My included files just had a `.kts` extension without the `.gradle.`