# how to add gradle (ideally using kotlin-dsl) to existing intellij python project

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There are some quite useful previous questions (especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966625/configure-intellij-auto-completion-for-gradle-script-in-kotlin) one but it is out of date and not a direct answer.

We have several python projects but are not moving into the world of kotlin.  I am looking to unify tools somewhat by introducing gradle to automate tasks within python projects.

I have added a working sample kotlin-dsl gradle script that automates the tasks successfully when launched from a shell, but where I am blocked is adding support for this to the intellij IDE.

The first challenge is simply configuring a python project to add gradle (currently gradle does not even appear on the tool windows menu.  I am thinking the python module can have python support allowing the overall project to have the jvm as this will be needed by gradle.  But what to do switch intellij to recognise the allready working build.gradle.kts file in the project root folder so tasks can be launced through the IDE and not just the shell?

Note: python dependancy support is not required at this time (as per the linked in).

Assistance appreciated.

Comment: There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20127. Also this feature might be helpful: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6990

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those seem to apply.  Using Intellij not pycharm because some projects already incorporate both python and kotlin components,  and this is not about implementing IDE configuration in gradle, but tasks not previously under the management of the IDE

Comment: I have made some progress on this and will update in a few hours.  Simplistically, adding a 'build.gradle', then restarting will add gradle to the project and that can then be deleted, and the configuration remains and adds some support for the 'build.gradle.kts' - but not full support such are allowing running the tasks from the file.  Still researching